# Suppressing renumbering of ordered lists in export

Tags: org-mode

I would like to refer to a few of Alan Perlis' Epigrams on Programming by their original numbers, but in an Org Mode ordered list.

When I export my document, the numbers I provide for the list items are discarded and replaced with new numbers, beginning with 1.

```
The raw source text:

#+begin_example
A few of Alan J. Perlis\rsquo{} [[http://www-pu.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/users/klaeren/epigrams.html][Epigrams on Programming]]:
   8. A programming language is low level when its programs require attention to the irrelevant.
  15. Everything should be built top-down, except the first time.
  31. Simplicity does not precede complexity, but follows it.
  54. Beware of the Turing tar-pit in which everything is possible but nothing of interest is easy.

#+end_example

The text as rendered, and renumbered, by export:

#begin_quote
A few of Alan J. Perlis\rsquo{} [[http://www-pu.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/users/klaeren/epigrams.html][Epigrams on Programming]]:
   8. A programming language is low level when its programs require attention to the irrelevant.
  15. Everything should be built top-down, except the first time.
  31. Simplicity does not precede complexity, but follows it.
  54. Beware of the Turing tar-pit in which everything is possible but nothing of interest is easy.
#end_quote
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the item number to whatever you want by beginning the text of the item with `[@8]` (for example).  [See *Ordered List* here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html).

A working example:

```
A list with custom ordering:
1. [@8] apple
1. [@77] orange
1. [@101] lime
```

When you export the document the list numbers will be 8, 77, and 101.